# Design pattern involving interaction between multiple datasources

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, dao

I have always used the DAO pattern for CRUD operations, each DAO in charge of accessing to a unique datasource at a time, and use generics to support multiple entities.

Now I require the same with the following changes

1.- Datasources will be added/removed dynamically at runtime

2.- A unit of work involve for instance: reading from datasource A, writing on B and deleting from A if B succeded. A and B will be interchangeable, which makes me think of some sort of origin/destination mechanism.

3.- Reads will only be done against 1 datasource only

The entities will be the same in all datasource, for which I could add a factory that creates a new DAO whenever a datasource is added, answering the first question. But I'm not sure how to address the rest.

Is the DAO pattern still suitable? If it is, what needs to be added? Or is there a different approach to this as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

If `Spring` is part of your application stack, You can use `AbstractRoutingDataSource` which will give the flexibility to add dynamic `datasource` mapping. If not go through the source code of it and you can build your own logic something similar to this.

On a quick google, I come across this http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/.
It is explaining this dynamic routing in action.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a business transaction. You need a business component covering the transaction, which involves multiple DAOs.

Comment: I understand, but the number of datasources is variable, perhaps a way of defining source/destination operations?

Comment: I believe, you already have the idea of how to solve your first question by using DAO Factory.